# Identify OSGI Bundle failure in Karaf programmatically

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

We are using Karaf-4 as OSGI container. We have several bundles associated with a feature. When any bundle fails in a feature, we want to identify programmatically. We tried BundleTracker and BundleListener, but we are not getting notification when a bundle fails after waiting in "GracePeriod" state.

We are able to view the status of failure bundle using "list" command in karaf console. We want to achieve this programmatically through notification rather than we execute "list" command in the karaf console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [BundleService](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/core/BundleService.java) as an OSGi service. The method getInfo gives you among other the BundleState. For failed bundles you can then call getDiag to get the detailed status.

Actually this is what the [diag](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/command/Diag.java) command does internally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that we can use BundleService to get details of a specific bundle. 

My requirement is, lets say i have 10 bundles getting installed as part of feature, one of the bundle got failed, is it possible for me to know the failed bundle name/id through listener/notification mechanism rather than me polling at regular intervals for all 10 bundles and checking their status.

Comment: You can look into the source of the blueprintstate module. It receives events from the blueprint extender to find about failed bundles. There are also bundle events maybe they can help with low level failures.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I have another query. I have registered JMX FeatureMBean to notify about feature installation status. In my feature i have 10 bundles and one of the bundle failed, but still my feature status shows "INSTALLED". I was expecting it to be in "UNINSTALLED" or "FAILURE" state

Comment: The feature installation only matches the OSGi requirements and capabilties as written in the Manifest of the bundles. It simply decides which bundles to install and does not check if the bundles all come up. Especially in the case of blueprint this would be difficult as the blueprint extender works asynchronously on the bundles.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.